# How to associate a functional to semi linear elliptic boundary value problem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

how to associate this functional $$I(u) := \int_{U}\frac{1}{2}\vert Du \vert^{2} - F(u)\; dx$$ to the Semilinear elliptic boundary-value problem 
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u=f(u),  & \text{in $U$ } \\
u=0, & \text{on $\partial U$ }  \\
\end{cases}
where $U$ is bounded subset of $\mathcal{R}^{n}$ and $F(z):= \int^{z}_{0} f(s) \, ds$ (refer book- Evans partial differential equation-page number 482, that is application to semilinear elliptic pde,in section - critical point, of chapter- The calculus of variation)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to understand why the PDE is the Euler-Lagrange equation of that functional?

Answer (score 2):

They are related by the fact that $I$ is the energy functional associated with the problem

$$\tag{1}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
 -\Delta u=f(u) &\mbox{ in $U$} \\
  u=0 &\mbox{ in $\partial U$}
       \end{array} \right.
$$

i.e. if $I'$ denotes the derivative of $I$, then (formally) $$\tag{2}\langle I'(u),v\rangle=\int_U Du\cdot Dv-\int_u f(u)v$$

Suppose tha tthe space we are working in is $H_0^1(U)$. If you can prove, for example, that there exist $u\in H_0^1(U)$ which satisfies $I'(u)=0$, or equivalently $\langle I'(u),v\rangle =0$ for all $v\in H_0^1(U)$, then $u$ is called a $\bf{\mbox{weak solution}}$ of $(1)$. Moreover, if such $u$ satisfies some regularity, for instance, if $u$ is in $H^2(U)$, then by using standard techiniques, you can prove that $u$ is a $\bf{\mbox{strong solution}}$ of $(1)$, i.e. $u$ satisfies $(1)$ a.e.

To conclude, if you can prove that your function is more regular, for example, it is $C^2$, then you do have a $\bf{\mbox{classical solution}}$.

Comment: what you mean by energy functional? pls help me i cant able to understand.pls

Comment: I have defined mathematically in $(2)$ what is a energy functional.